# How to override Extensible Service Proxy error response

Tags: nginx, proxy, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-endpoints

I am using google cloud endpoints with Extensible Service Proxy and running my code on kubernetes.

When i send a bad request example:- Not passing token in headers, i get a detailed response, telling me what headers are required, however i want 400 Bad Request